# How many years are remaining in Kali Yuga?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, kali-yuga

Could anybody tell me how many years are remaining in Kali Yuga?

Comment: The answer is stated in this url www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/7/38

Comment: There is no consensus among scholars when Kali Yuga ends. Majority of people think Kali Yuga ends after 4,27,000 years, But some scholars say that **factor 360 inflated** the size of Yugas.